# How to design a video view with curved edges in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable, android-videoview

In my application, I want to display videoview as a rounded corners. I have tried placing videoview inside linearlayout with rounded corner set to linearlayout. but it does not work perfectly. I can not set rounded corner to videoview. so how to design videoview with curved edges?

Comment: How about adding a mask on top of VideoView?

Answer (score 0):

Create an xml file in drawable folder called shape_video.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
       <corners android:radius="6dp" />
 </shape>
```

Change the radius according to your requirement and in the background attribute of your videoview, give

```
android:background="@drawable/shape_video"
```

Comment: ya i have tried it in the same way still its not working

Comment: it should work, can you post all your xml file here ? update in question !!

Answer (score 0):

You specifiy the drawable with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="10dip"/>
    <stroke
    android:width="5dip"
    android:color="@color/blue" />
</shape>
```

Then you have to specify the drawable as being in the foreground:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:foreground="@drawable/border"
    android:padding="5dp">
    <VideoView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/VideoView1"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```